# GUI builder для Сlojure

Tags: gui, clojure

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли использовать визуальные редакторы графического интерфейса для Java для работы с языком программирования Clojure?

Мне хотя бы простейший пример: вот создали в GUI builder кнопку сохранили все,а на Сlojure создали обработчик события для этой кнопки. Т.е. я не хочу руками в коде этот интерфейс создавать, а создать его в IDE, а уже потом с ним взаимодействовать. Как то так, ну или хотя бы может в интернете где то об этом написано, я не нашел(

Comment: Можно написать GUI обертку на более традиционных языках программирования, например C# или Delphi, который будет вызывать Ваш скрипт.

Comment: так я и хочу на Java ( в какой либо популярной IDE типа IntelliJ IDEA или NetBeans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам нашел [Playing around with JavaFX and Clojure](http://drowsy.de/blog/?p=7)

Answer (score 2):

[[@cyberdream](/users/8768/cyberdream)](/users/8768/cyberdream): http://clojure.org/java_interop?

Хотя, я бы структурировал программу, и использовал Java для View и возможно контроллера, а Clojure оставил для модели/бэкэнда.